# Split wide HTML page to multiple pages PDF using Phantomjs

Tags: pdf, split, phantomjs

I have a HTML page generated by meteorjs with dimensions width: 4860px, height: 480px. When I export the page to PDF using phantomjs using width and height for viewportSize and paperSize, the page renders to a single PDF file, that is not printable.
Is there a way to set viewportSize and paperSize in a way so that my output is split into several pages, let's say A4 size?